# Shell - saving contents of file to variable then outputting the variable

Tags: shell, variables

First off, I'm really bad at shell, as you'll notice :)

Now then, I have the following task: The script gets two arguments (fileName, N). If the number of lines in the file is greater then N, then I need to cut the last N lines, then overwrite the contents of the file with it.

I thought of saving the contents of the file into a variable, then just cat-ing that to the file. However for some reason it's not working.

I have problems with saving the last N lines to a variable.

This is how I tried doing it:

```
lastNLines=`tail -$2 $1`
cat $lastNLines > $1
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but wouldn't `tail -n N inFile > outFile` be good enough?

Comment: @pfnuesel the problem is the OP wants to overwrite the same file he's reading from.

Comment: `tail -n N inFile > outFile && mv outFile inFile`

Comment: @pfnuesel By the looks of it, he's trying to write to the same file he's reading from. When you end something in >$1, Bash will open it for writing, thus emptying the file, before executing `tail`. In other words, `tail` would just find an empty file.

Comment: I still don't see why my suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: @pfnuesel it would, OP just seems to be searching for a solution without the use of temporary files, at least that's what I took away from his tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments `cat` takes are file names, not the content.

Instead, you can use a temp file, like this:

```
tail -$2 $1 > $1._tmp
mv $1._tmp $1
```

To save the content to a variable, you can do what you already included in your question, or:

```
lastNLines=`cat $1`
```

(after the `mv` command, of course)

Comment: Okay, and how about saving the contents of the file to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your `lastNLines` is not a filename. `cat` takes filenames. You also cannot open the input file for writing, because the shell truncates it before `tail` can get to it, which is why you need to use a temporary file.

However, if you insist on not using a temporary file, here's a non-portable solution:

```
tail -n$2 $1 | sponge $1
```

You may need to install `moreutils` for `sponge`.